# Where are the parameters for Indy's TIdCompressorZLib.CompressStream Method documented?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy, zlib

The TIdComproessorZLib component is used for compression and decompression in the Delphi/C++ Builder Indy library.  The CompressStream Method has the following definition:

```
public: virtual __fastcall CompressStream(TStream AInStream, TStream AOutStream, const TIdCompressionLevel ALevel, const int AWindowBits, const int AMemLevel, const int AStrategy);
```

The complete description of those parameters in the help file is:

> CompressStream is a public overridden procedure. that implements the
>   abstract the virtual method declared in the ancestor class.
>
> AInStream is the stream containing the uncompressed contents used in
>   the compression operation.
>
> AOutStream is the stream used to store the compressed contents from
>   the compression operation. AOutStream is cleared prior to outputting
>   the compressed contents from the operation. When AOutStream is
>   omitted, the stream in AInStream is cleared and reused for the output
>   from the compression operation.
>
> Use ALevel to indicate the desired compression level for the
>   operation.
>
> Use AWindowsBits and AMemLevel to control the memory footprint
>   required to perform in-memory compression using the ZLib library.
>
> Use AStrategy to control the RLE-encoding strategy used in the
>   compression operation.

ALevel's values defined on the help page for TIdCompressionLevel, but I cannot find any indication of what values should be used for AWindowBits, AMemLevel, or AStrategy, which are just integers.

I looked in the source code, but CompressStream just delegates to IndyCompressStream, which is listed in the help file as:

```
IndyCompressStream(TStream InStream, TStream OutStream, const int level = Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, const int WinBits = MAX_WBITS, const int MemLevel = MAX_MEM_LEVEL, const int Stratagy = Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
```

The help for IndyCompressStream doesn't even list the minimal description of the parameters that CompressStream does.

I tracked down the file where (I think) those default constants mentioned in IndyCompressStream live, source\Indy10\Protocols\IdZLibHeaders.pas, and they are

```
  Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY    = 0;
  Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION  = -1;
  MAX_WBITS = 15; { 32K LZ77 window }
  MAX_MEM_LEVEL = 9;
```

However, the value given for `Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION` is not even a legal value for that parameter according to the documentation for `TIdCompressionLevel`

Is there some documentation somewhere about what AWindowBits, AMemLevel, and AStrategy mean to this component, and what values are reasonable to use for them?  Are the values listed above the actual recommended defaults?  Also, the source files include "indy", "Indy10", and "indyimpl" directories.  Which of those should we be using to find the source for the current Indy components?

Thanks!

Comment: Now that is how to ask a question.  Well done.

Comment: What are hoping to do with it?

Comment: Does Indy have documentation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: [Indy has documentation](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx), but it has not been updated in a long time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: is there a way we can contribute to updating the documentation?

Comment: @nachbar: that is a good question. I can make edits to Indy's website, but I'm not sure how to edit Indy's help files and online doc pages (I will have to see if they are even in the same system as the website). I did not write any of the docs, just the code. I'll have to look into whether we can maybe switch to a wiki or something so users can contribute docs easier. In the meantime, you can submit doc changes to Indy's dev team and we'll forward them to the docs team.

Comment: May I suggest Indy move to a DocWiki? I promise to contribute much edits to that DocWiki if you start it.

Comment: @WarrenP: I did suggest that possibility to the other Indy admins. We're considering options right now. I'm also going to be evaluating [Documentation Insight](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/) as another option, too.

Comment: That would be good. I'll help with that if that is what you guys decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to look to the zlib documentation in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Constants).  In particular, the [parameters to `deflateInit2()`](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced).

In nearly all cases, the only ones you should mess with are the compression level and the window bits.  For window bits, you would normally leave the window size at 32K (15), but either add 16 for the gzip format (31), or negate (-15) to get the raw deflate format with no header or trailer.  For some special kinds of data, you may get an improvement with a different compression strategy, e.g. image or other numerical arrays of data.

Comment: Nothing like getting one of the authors of zlib to answer my question!  Thanks!  The one thing I did need to change was that I was trying to create a gzip format, since that is what my server was expecting, and that requires adding 16 to windowBits, as documented in the zlib reference you provided for deflateInit2().

Comment: Ah, yes, often that one is messed with as well.  I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the comments and answers, especially Remy and Mark.  I had not realized that the Indy units were wrappers around zlib, and that the parameters were defined in the zlib library.

I was trying to create a gzip format stream for uploading to a server that was expecting gzip.

Here is the working code for gzip compression and decompression:

```c
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TStringStream* streamIn = new TStringStream(String("This is some data to compress"));
TMemoryStream* streamCompressed = new TMemoryStream;
TStringStream* streamOut = new TStringStream;

/* this also works to compress to gzip format, but you must #include <IdZlib.hpp>
CompressStreamEx(streamIn, streamCompressed, Idzlib::clDefault, zsGZip); */

// NOTE: according to docs, you can leave outstream null, and instream 
// will be replaced and reused, but I could not get that to work

IdCompressorZLib1->CompressStream(                
    streamIn,            // System::Classes::TStream* AInStream,
    streamCompressed,    // System::Classes::TStream* AOutStream,
    1,                   // const Idzlibcompressorbase::TIdCompressionLevel ALevel,
    15 + 16,             // const int AWindowBits, -- add 16 to get gzip format
    8,                   // const int AMemLevel, -- see note below
    0);                  // const int AStrategy);

    streamCompressed->Position = 0;
    IdCompressorZLib1->DecompressGZipStream(streamCompressed, streamOut);

    String out = streamOut->DataString;
    ShowMessage(out);
}
```

In particular, note that passing -1 for ALevel produces ZLib Error -2, Z_STREAM_ERROR which means invalid parameter, in spite of the defaults I had found.  Also, AWindowBits normally ranges from 8 to 15, but adding 16 gives you a gzip format, and negative numbers give you a raw format, as described in the zlib documentation referenced by Mark Adler, one of the authors of the zlib library.  I changed AMemLevel from Indy's default per Mark Adler's comment.

Also, as noted the CompressStreamEx function will produce gzip compression using the parameters included in the comments above.

The above was tested in RAD Studio XE3.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Leaving `memLevel` at the default of 8 usually results in better compression, by virtue of adapting the Huffman codes to the data more often.

Comment: Thanks.  I have adjusted the code above to reflect that, and tested in RAD Studio XE3 again.